# Are there more efficent methods for creating multiple SQL statements in R, than using lapply and paste()

Tags: r

As part of a larger application we are using R for analytics and storing the results in an SQLlite database. We are having issues when updating a fairly large number of rows with distinct values in our SQLite database (approximately 30,000 rows). The operation is taking approximately 40 seconds, which is a bit too long for our needs.
The problem does not seem to be with the SQLite update statement itself but appears more to be with how we are building the statement string: We iterate over a list using lapply, submitting the queries to the DB each iteration.  The list stores the values and the list item names are the row key used. We build the update strings using the paste function. Our code is as follows:

```
p.db.storeList <- function(column.name, values) {
  #Note: list must have the row ids as the item names
  #connect to DB
  con <- p.db.connection()
  #start TXN
  dbBegin(con)
  #build update statement for each item in the list, 
  # using the item name as a row id
  q <-""
  lapply(names(values), function(rowName) {
    q<<-paste("UPDATE data SET ", column.name, " = ", values[rowName], " WHERE row =",      rowName,sep="")
    DBI::dbSendQuery(con, q)    
  })
  #end TXN
  dbCommit(con)
  DBI::dbDisconnect(con)
}
```

Using Rprof to profile our code , it turned out that the paste command was taking up over 60% of the run time, far outweighing the amount of time of the actual update itself.

```
> summaryRprof()
$by.self
                        self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"paste"                     23.98    64.22      23.98     64.22
".Call"                      3.90    10.44       3.90     10.44
"ls"                         0.96     2.57       1.28      3.43
"standardGeneric"            0.66     1.77      11.78     31.55
"match"                      0.56     1.50       1.86      4.98
"possibleExtends"            0.54     1.45       1.28      3.43
"is"                         0.46     1.23      12.12     32.46
".getClassFromCache"         0.44     1.18       0.90      2.41
".identC"                    0.44     1.18       0.74      1.98
```

We would like to reduce the amount of time this function takes by any means necessary. Is there a more efficient way to build the SQL update strings than using the paste() function within an lapply loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `<<-` within `lapply`? It doesn't seem like you need `q` outside of the loop (and is bad practice). It seems to me like you should use a `for` loop anyway. `lapply` should be used if you need a list of return values.

Don't use a loop to create the `q`s. `paste` is vectorized:

```
column.name <- "x"
rowName <- c("A", "B")
values <- 1:2

paste0("UPDATE data SET ", column.name, " = ", values, " WHERE row =", rowName)
#[1] "UPDATE data SET x = 1 WHERE row =A" "UPDATE data SET x = 2 WHERE row =B"
```

Then use a `for` loop over this vector to send the queries.

Comment: We (I'm involved as well) did the "<<-" to test if creating a string in every call of the function passed to lapply, was one source of the problem. Initially, we just had the q inside the function. Anyhow, it didn't make any significant difference. I didn't understand the vectorized part, but your solution seems pretty much what we need. Testing after the weekend.

Comment: Worked perfectly, It reduced the time to less than a third of what it was. Thank you.